# Is there an openldap core schema reference?

Tags: openldap

I am looking for the openldap common core schemas reference and although I have found [this reference](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ape/) I have been warned with extreme caution (and insulted in some cases) not to rely on this source for accuracy. So I would greatly appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the insults. I've always found that source reliable. However the references for core.schema are the RFCs cited in the source code.